# ENVVARS for Shiny Appshot

Tags: r, shiny, snapshot

I'm trying to take a snapshot of my Shiny App using webshot where the user can pre-set the input variables. I think appshot within the webshot package can do this...it says that the envvars argument should be :

"A named character vector or named list of environment variables and values to set for the Shiny app’s R process.  These will be unset after the process exits. This can be used to pass configuration information to a Shiny app"

Basically what I want is this:

```
appdir <- system.file("examples", "01_hello", package="shiny")
names = list(bins = 7)
appshot(appdir, "Picture.png",envvars = names)
```

But this doesn't have the desired result. What should the syntax of envvars look like to change the desired # of bins to 7?